# Is there a multi purpose Stream decompressor?

Tags: linux, compression

I was always wondering if there is a multi purposes stream decompressor.
I only found atool, but that could only handle files not streams, trying to use it with named pipes ended in the error "not a regular file"
I experimented a little with trying to do a script that does it.

```
#/bin/sh
tempfile=$(mktemp)
fileformat=$(dd bs=1 count=20 2>/dev/null | tee $tempfile | file - | cut -f 2 -d " ")
case $fileformat in

  LZMA)
    (cat $tempfile; rm $tempfile; cat) |lzma -d
    ;;

  gzip)
    (cat $tempfile; rm $tempfile; cat) |gzip -d
    ;;

  bzip2)
    (cat $tempfile; rm $tempfile; cat) |pbzip2 -d
    ;;

  lzop)
    (cat $tempfile; rm $tempfile; cat) |lzop -d -f
    ;;

  LZ4)
    (cat $tempfile; rm $tempfile; cat) |lz4 -d -c
    ;;

  XZ)
    (cat $tempfile; rm $tempfile; cat) |xz -d -f
    ;;

esac
```

it seems to work, but I don't realy like the code. It uses a temporary file for the firs 20 bytes. Trying to put the first 20 bytes into a variable ended up in Null Bytes ignored. Also it was just a guess with trial and error of how many bytes I need for file to identify the stream. And I don't realy like that there is no check if the decompressors are available, especialy bzip2 where there are two decompressors bzip2 and pbzip2.

Before I try to expand the code I want to know if it is realy worth it or if there is already some sort of multi purpose stream decompressor

greetings.

Comment: You forgot zstandard and brotli and old school compress.

Comment: Yes of course there could be even more that i missed so I was wondering if the work might be already done by somone and if there is a solution that already exists.
Also brotoli does not seem to be recognized by file it says only data

Comment: The standard perl [`IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress) module handles a fair number of formats. Usage would be something like `perl -MIO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress=anyuncompress -e 'anyuncompress "-", "-"' < foo.xz | something`

Comment: Interessting but seems only to work with bzip and gzip correctly

$ echo Hello World |xz -9 |perl -MIO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress=anyuncompress -e 'anyuncompress "-", "-"' 
�7zXZ�ִF!�X�
           Hello World
"�u?��8>$
         �▒����}YZ

$ 
$ echo Hello World |lz4 -9 |perl -MIO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress=anyuncompress -e 'anyuncompress "-", "-"' 
"M▒d@�
      �Hello World
���

$ echo Hello World |lzma  -9 |perl -MIO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress=anyuncompress -e 'anyuncompress "-", "-"' 
]��������$I�o�_�Պ����